# VM software for raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I have found an ISO image which i will be using for emulation of PSX games. I was wondering if I could run it within Raspbian or if I have to actually reboot the Pi and switch to my emulator!

Thank you!

L.

Comment: Is the image compiled for ARMv6 to start with?  There's no X86 simulator if that's what you mean.  I don't think there's hardware level VM's period, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you booted the Pi with the emulator successfully?

Answer (score 1):

A least a "Raspberry Pi 2" is required to emulate PS1.

pcsx can be installed and configured on Raspbian and used without reboot.

The RetroPie distribution is ready for game files.